# Superscripts and subscripts in ylab() function

Tags: rstudio

This code might be a little messy (just starting to use R), but I'm looking for help to get subscripts and superscripts using ggplot2 and ylab().

I need a superscripted -1 after the mL in lab():
chaptoplot=ggplot(chaptodat, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, shape=treatment))+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +geom_line(position=pd) +geom_point(position=pd, size=4) + ylab("Corrected haptoglobin \nconcentration (mg mL)\n") + theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+theme_classic()+theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=12))+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12)) +theme(legend.position="none") +ylim(0.2,0.7)

For this code, I need a subscripted 405 after the OD in ylab():
natabplot=ggplot(natabdat, aes(x=bin, y=mean, shape=treatment)) +geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +geom_line(position=pd) +geom_point(position=pd, size=4) +xlab("\nTime of sampling") +ylab("Total circulating IgY\n(corrected OD)\n")+theme_bw() +theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+theme_classic()+theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=12))+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12))+theme(legend.position="none")

I've tried searching using ^"-1" and ["405"], but it either doesn't work or I get an error message. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Next time you won't need to write all your code, otherwise people would rather not read it. Just write the important part of your code, with the special code block ctrl+k.

However, you should write something like that:

```
chaptoplot = ggplot(chaptodat, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, shape=treatment)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +geom_point(position=pd, size=4) + 
ylab(expression("Corrected haptoglobin \nconcentration "("mg mL"^"-1")\n))) + 
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=12)) +
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12)) +
theme(legend.position="none") +
ylim(0.2,0.7)
```

The other one should be as follows:

```
natabplot = ggplot(natabdat, aes(x=bin, y=mean, shape=treatment)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +
geom_point(position=pd, size=4) +
xlab("\nTime of sampling") +
ylab(expression("Corrected haptoglobin \nconcentration"("mg mL"^"-1")))+
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
theme_classic()+theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=12)) +
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12)) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```